# vuejs debug error "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to make a notification that the status is not selected, but I get the error "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"
How can I fix this?

```
<div class="select-item" v-for="(type, index) in typeStatus" v-bind:key="type.id" v-on:click="status = index; addedForm = false;">
{{ type.name }}</div>

search() {
    this.filter.status = this.typeStatus[this.status].id
    this.$emit('filter', this.filter)
    if (this.filter.status == null) {
        return alert('Please select status')
    }
},
```

Comment: How does your `typeStatus` look like?

Comment: <span v-else>{{ typeStatus[status].name }}</span>
typeStatus: []

Comment: Try `:key="index"` instead of `v-bind:key="type.id"`

Comment: If you've got an `id` value, using `index` is a poor alternative. Looking at just the code you've got here, I don't believe there's anything here that shouldn't be working... the error means that `type` is coming up as undefined for some reason, which doesn't make much sense.